# On server side, get the server IP to which client is connected

Tags: linux, sockets

Server has multiple interfaces. Server is bound to 0.0.0.0 which means it is listening on all the interfaces it has. So, client can connect using any one of these server IPs.
So, on the server side how to get the IP to which client is connected.

Comment: @UlugToprak , I want IP of SERVER  and not the IP of client.

Comment: wording wasn't clear, i removed the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getsockname()` on the socket returned by `accept()`, it will be bound to the local address that your server is using to communicate with the accepted client.

```
NAME
     getsockname — get socket name
LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <sys/socket.h>

     int
     getsockname(int s, struct sockaddr * restrict name,
     socklen_t * restrict namelen);

DESCRIPTION
     The getsockname() system call returns the current name for the specified
     socket.  The namelen argument should be initialized to indicate the
     amount of space pointed to by name.  On return it contains the actual
     size of the name returned (in bytes).
```

Comment: It will *return* the address the *client* is using to communicate with *this server.*

Comment: @EJP : no, you are totally wrong, **on the server side** getsockname returns the server address, as I wrote. It's getpeername that returns the client address. I do not understand that you vote -1 for my answer (getsockname) and give the same answer (getsockname) just after that ! Not fair, the way you are working with SO.

Comment: At the server, `getsockname()` returns the address the client used to connect to the server, which can be any of the server's IP addresses, which is what the question is about: which one. There is no contradiction here. The client's *own* address, which the 'server is using  to communicate with the client', is returned by `getpeername()` at the server.

Comment: Again, you are wrong because you forgot that there are two addresses in an IP datagram, for the server to communicate with the client: the client address and the server address. Each time you write about an address that *the client is using to communicate with this server*, this does not make any sense because you do not specify which of those two addresses you speak about. Moreover, your answer was strictly the same as mine: getsockname.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo: what EJP says is correct. `getsockname()` is the socket's **LOCAL** address, whereas `getpeername()` is the **REMOTE** address. On the server side, the local address is the listening address the client `connect`ed to, and the remote address is the address the client `connect`ed from. So, "*the address the client is using to communicate with this server*" is referring to the server's local address, while "*the address the server is using to communicate with the client*" is referring to the client's remote address.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: please, tell me what is wrong in what I said in my response? (*Use getsockname() on the socket returned by accept(), it will be bound to the address your server is using to communicate with the corresponding client*)

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo: I didn't say your answer is wrong.  It is not.  Your comments to EJP are wrong, telling him he's wrong when he is not.  You both have the same answer, describing the same thing, just worded differently. Leave it at that and move on.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: OK, so here is what happened: I answered something you consider right, then EJP made a comment where he changed "local address that your server is using" in my text by "the address the client is using" in its comment and simultaneously voted -1 for my answer. So, I've understood that he thought my answer was wrong. This is why I replied him he was wrong. After that, he added the same reply as mine ("using getsockname"). Now, I think, and say, that it is not fair. Have a nice day on SO.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo You should be thanking me for the correction. You don't have any infiormation about who downvoted this answer.

Comment: @EJP: why have you published the same answer than mine after having said I was wrong? Really? Why do you want people to thank you? Is it so important for you?

Answer (score 0):

This information is available via the `getsockname()` call.  When called on the server side, it provides the local server address that the server `accept`ed the client on.

Note that this is subject to an abstruse thing called the 'weak end system model', which essentially means that the local interface the connection was received by doesn't necessarily correspond to the IP address used by the client (think what happens when proxies/routers are in between the client and server). In which case, you won't be able to the actual IP that the client actually `connect`ed to (unless the client sends it to the server in a data packet), only the IP on the server that accepted the client.